Image array not showing in Unity inspector
I'm trying to create a lives system of five hearts in a game I'm making, so to do that I created a life tracked script:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Unity.VisualStudio.Editor;
using UnityEngine;

public class LifeTracker : MonoBehaviour
{
  public int lives;

  public Image[] hearts;
  public Sprite heartImage;


}

However, when I go to Unity, the inspector will only show the int and Sprite:

I've tried rewriting and reloading the script, but nothing's worked. I tried changing it to "public Image[] hearts = new Image[5];" but have had no change.
Where am I going wrong? Does Unity not allow arrays in the inspector anymore? I'm new to Unity, but I'm not that new, and everywhere I look it says that this should work. Am I missing something obvious?

I think you want to reference UnityEngine.UI.Image, but there is a line using Microsoft.Unity.VisualStudio.Editor; among the using directives, so you actually referenced the wrong class: Microsoft.Unity.VisualStudio.Editor.Image.
The solution is:
//using Microsoft.Unity.VisualStudio.Editor;
using UnityEngine.UI;

Tip: The most likely reason for this issue is that Visual Studio will default prompt for unimported types, and you lack attention. You can turn off this feature. Check this question: Stop Visual Studio from adding using statements (Visual Studio 2022 edition)

Test it
SerializedProperty hearts;


private void OnEnable()
{
hearts = serializedObject.FindProperty("hearts");
}

private void OnInspectorGUI ()
{
serializedObject.Update();
  EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(hearts, true);
  serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();}

And please check the below link:
Unity Editor Gui Layoit
Alternative solution:
private void OnInspectorGUI ()
{
 serializedObject.Update();

hearts.isExpanded = EditorGUILayout.Foldout(hearts.isExpanded, hearts.name);
if(hearts.isExpanded)
{
    EditorGUI.indentLevel++;

    // The field for item count
    hearts.arraySize = EditorGUILayout.IntField("size", hearts.arraySize);

    // draw item fields
    for(var i = 0; i< hearts.arraySize; i++)
    {
        var item = hearts.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(item, new GUIContent($"Element {i}");
    }

    EditorGUI.indentLevel--;
}
serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
}

